# Folder permissions would changed in cross functions

Tags: php, file-permissions

I have following code in php and I want make a simple directory with user defined permissions.

```
MakeDir("test",0777);
function MakeDir($dir,$mode=0777){
    echo $mode;
    mkdir($dir, $mode) ;  
}
```

for 0777 function returns 511, and for 0666 it returns 438.
How can I protect main input for chmode or mkdir command?

Answer (score 1):

stringyfy your arguments like

```
MakeDir("test",'0777');
function MakeDir($dir,$mode='0777'){
    echo $mode;
}
```

Comment: Your answer works for echo, print etc. But it returns wrong results when a directory would be created.